# Activity Tracker and Elliptical

Tags: running, calories

I own the Fitbit Force, and wanted to know if I were to wear it while running, elliptical or stairclimber does it convert the miles/floors to calories burnt?  If I were to also use runkeeper are the miles/calories double counted?  Also, If I manually enter in an activity and wear the Fitbit does it also double count the calories.  Just wanting to see if I should wear my fitbit while on the elliptical or other activities and just manually enter in data.  Thanx!

Comment: see also: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22127/fitbit-flex-accuracy-in-counting-steps?lq=1

Comment: and: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22578/active-minutes-on-flex?lq=1